# Save as date and time not working

Tags: vba, excel

It is supposed to save as file name: Folder\test location 'what ever is in cell C27' and then data and time. I am getting :'008 11 2015 00 00 00'. How do I clean this up with out using "/" and ":"? Note the first 0 is just the test number I used.

Also this macro is in a template that the Testing software uses that is why it has to use Auto_open but the other problem is that when it saves as a non template file, upon opening it tries to run the macro in the non template file. How can I make it so the macro does not save in or is disabled in the save as files/ non template files?

```
Sub Auto_Open()

Dim FileName    As String
Dim FilePath    As String
Dim FileDate    As String

MyNote = "Is Cell 'C27' Overview Information" & SavePath & " Location_1,2,3,or 4?"

Answer = MsgBox(MyNote, vbQuestion + vbYesNo)

If Answer = vbYes Then

    FilePath = "C:\Users\aholiday\Desktop\FRF_Data_Macro_Insert_Test"
    FileName = Sheets("Data").Range("C27").Text
    ThisWorkbook.SaveAs FileName:=FilePath & "\" & FileName

    Dim FileCopyName    As String
    Dim FileCopyPath    As String

    FilePath = "C:\Users\aholiday\Desktop\Backup"
    FileName = Sheets("Data").Range("C27").Text
    FileDate = Format(Date, "mm dd yyyy hh mm ss")
    ThisWorkbook.SaveAs FileName:=FilePath & "\" & FileName & FileDate

    MsgBox "File was saved!"

    MyNote = "Open FRF Data Sheet?(After Forth Test Only)"

    Answer = MsgBox(MyNote, vbQuestion + vbYesNo)

    If Answer = vbYes Then

        Workbooks.Open ("FRF_Data_Sheet_Template.xlsm")

    Else
        MsgBox "Ready for Next Test, Please Exit."
    End If

Else
    MsgBox "File was not saved, Please Use Location_1,2,3or,4 Durring SIG ATM Test"
End If

End Sub
```

Solved:

```
  Sub Auto_Open()

  With Range("A30")
  .Value = Time
  .NumberFormat = "h-mm-ss AM/PM"
  End With


    Dim FileName    As String
    Dim FilePath    As String
    Dim FileDate    As String

    MyNote = "Is Cell 'B27' Overview Information" & SavePath & " Location1,2,3,or 4?"

    Answer = MsgBox(MyNote, vbQuestion + vbYesNo)

    If Answer = vbYes Then

        FilePath = "C:\Users\aholiday\Desktop\FRF_Data_Macro_Insert_Test"
        FileName = Sheets("Data").Range("C27").Text
        ThisWorkbook.SaveAs FileName:=FilePath & "\" & FileName

        Dim FileCopyName    As String
        Dim FileCopyPath    As String
        Dim FileTime        As String

        FilePath = "C:\Users\aholiday\Desktop\Backup"
        FileName = Sheets("Data").Range("B27").Text
        FileTime = Sheets("Data").Range("A30").Text


        ThisWorkbook.SaveAs FileName:=FilePath & "\" & FileName & FileTime & ".xlsx", FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook

        MsgBox "File was saved!"
        MsgBox "Ready for Next Test, Please Exit."


    Else
    MsgBox "File was not saved, Please Use Location_1,2,3or,4 Durring SIG ATM Test"
    End If

 End Sub
```

Comment: Use Format(FileDate, "ShortDate")

Comment: For Windows, filenames cannot use the special characters: `\ / : * ? " < > | `. And Change `Date` to `Now` as the former does not give the time portion (HHMMSS). Finally include the extension ".xlsx."

Comment: Is there any way to make it give the time? I have one folder that the macro saves file name Location1, Location2, Location3,and Location 4. And every time i complete a test those four files get overwriten by the next test results because another file pulls data from those, that is why i have save as back up which is going to save all past results, but it cant be Just location1,2,3,4 and date seeing that there will be many test in one day. If there isnt away for the macro to save as file name with time/date then how about a macro that inputs the time into a cell and then could save as that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't have a \ in a filename.

For the date part, use the format function. You can define the date format if you want by using "MM-dd-yyy"

```
ThisWorkbook.SaveAs FileName:=FilePath & "\" & FileName & Format(FileDate, "MM-dd-yyyy") & ".xlsx", FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook
```

Use the FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook to save it as a workbook without macros.

Comment: VBA Format `Short Date` still includes forward slashes not allowed in file names as in `MM/DD/YYYY`. Second, OP is using `Format()`.

Comment: Correct Parfait. Thanks.

Comment: I wonder why everyone is focused on removing slashes. The OP does not have them. `FileDate = Format(Date, "mm dd yyyy hh mm ss")` puts `008 11 2015 00 00 00` into `FileDate`. The OP, if I'm not mistaken, is asking how to introduce `/` and `:` into that. The answer should be: you can't, keep using what you have.

Comment: Gives Run time error '1004' Method 'SaveAs' of object'_Workbook failed